# How to reverse a map

Tags: java, guava

Let's take a map :

- A -> {1, 2, 3}
- B -> {3, 4, 5}
- C -> {2, 3, 5}

I need to reverse this map and obtain :

- 1 -> {A}
- 2 -> {A, C}
- 3 -> {A, B, C}
- 4 -> {B}
- 5 -> {B, C}

I achieved to do it with this code :

```
public static <U, V> Map<V, Set<U>> reverseMap(Map<U, Set<V>> map) {
  Map<V, Set<U>> result = Maps.newHashMap();
  for(Map.Entry<U, Set<V>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    for(V value : entry.getValue()) {

      Set<U> set = result.get(value);
      if(set == null) {
        set = Sets.newHashSet();
        result.put(value, set);
      }
      set.add(entry.getKey());
      result.put(value, set);
    }

  }
  return result;
}
```

But this is only a reverse indexing so I think that there might exist a predefined method somewhere to do this.

Do someone knows such a library? a method in Guava?

Comment: I guess what You are looking for are Multimaps (http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Multimaps) especially http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#invertFrom%28com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20M%29

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Hm, quite right. I retract my statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you replace your `HashMap<U, Set<V>>` by a `HashMultimap<U, V>` (they're equivalent, and the `Multimap` is easier to use), you can now use [`Multimaps.invertFrom()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#invertFrom%28com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20M%29) which will populate a `Multimap<V, U>`.

---

Note that as the Javadoc mentions, if you use an [`ImmutableMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultimap.html), you can then directly call [`ImmutableMultimap.inverse()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultimap.html#inverse%28%29).

Comment: I read https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Multimaps to understand. Exactly what I needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using streams:

```java
Map<V, Set<U>> invertedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                .map(v -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), v)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toSet())));
```

## Step-by-step breakdown

1. Convert the map to a stream of entries

   ```java
   // Stream<Map.Entry<U, Set<V>>>
   map.entrySet().stream()
   ```
2. Split apart each entry into a separate item per item in the value list

   ```java
   // Stream<Map.Entry<U, V>>
   .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), v)))
   ```
3. Group the entries into a new map, with keys equal to the previous values, and values containing a list of each original key mapped to that value.

   ```java
   // Map<V, Set<U>>
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
           Map.Entry::getValue,
           Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toSet())));
   ```